# using celery with pyramid and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, celery, pyramid, celeryd

I've been able to deploy a test application by using pyramid with pserve and running pceleryd (I just send an email without blocking while it is sent).

But there's one point that I don't understand: I want to run my application with mod_wsgi, and I don't understand if I can can do it without having to run pceleryd from a shell, but if I can do something in the virtualhost configuration.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are technically ways you could use Apache/mod_wsgi to manage a process distinct from that handling web requests, but the pain point is that Celery will want to fork off further worker processes. Forking further processes from a process managed by Apache can cause problems at times and so is not recommended.

You are thus better of starting up Celery process separately. One option is to use supervisord to start it up and manage it.